# Url.ActionLink results in 404 error despite routing to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

On my ASP MVC 3 page, when the user selects an item from the drop down list with no corresponding values, I dynamically create a fieldset which contains a button with an `onclick()` method. When the user types a value in the input box for the field they would like to create and then clicks the button, I am trying to route them to the `Create` controller action with the appropriate parameters (the item selected in the drop down list and the text the user has just input). However, each and every time I click on the button I receive a 404 error.

I've set a breakpoint at the start of the `Create` method in the controller and it is never tripped, so I know that the problem isn't what's being rendered and sent back to the view, it's the original attempt to reach the `Create` controller (although I understand this was probably evident from the 404 error :)

I've checked the URL, and it is rendering properly so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the jquery/ajax that creates the fieldset

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var globalCreate = '@Url.Action("Create", "DropDownValues")';
        var globalEdit = '@Url.Action("Edit", "DropDownValues")';

        $('#Categories').change(function () {
            var displayPage = $('#Categories option:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("getItems","DropDownValues")',
                data: { model: displayPage },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "") {
                        //Clear edits if necessary
                        if ($('#edits').html()) {
                            $('#edits').empty();
                        }

                        $('#edits').append('<fieldset style=width:250px;><legend>No fields yet</legend>' +
                                                '<div class=editor-label>' +
                                                'Enter field name' +
                                                '</div>' + 
                                                '<div class=editor-field>' +
                                                '<input type="text" id="newField" />' +
                                                '</div>' + 
                                                '<button onclick="addItems()">Add Items</button>' +
                                                '</fieldset>');
                    } else {
```

and here is the onclick method

```
    function addItems(){
        window.location.href = ('@Url.Action("Create", "DropDownValues")' + '/' + $('#Categories option:selected').text() + '/' + $('#newField').val());
    }
```

Right now, if I were to select the `Testing display` drop down item, type `asdf` into the input box and click the buttonn, the following URL would be rendered

```
http://localhost:2574/DropDownValues/Create/Testing%20display/asdf
```

here is the method signature from the controller

```
    public ActionResult Create(string model, string field)
    {
```

Comment: how does your `create` action method looks like ?

Comment: Given what you've shown so far, `DropDownValues` is the controller and `Create` is the action. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the parameter names in the url.

```
function addItems()
{
  var newUrl="@Url.Action("Create", "DropDownValues")?model="+
                     $('#Categories option:selected').text() +
                    "&field=" + $('#newField').val();
  window.location.href = newUrl;
}
```

You may also consider encoding the querystring values. You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method for that.

**For CREATE / UPDATE/ DELETE operations, it is not a good idea to use a GET request. You should use a POST request**. (Bots / search engines /or a angry user can delete your data/ keep adding junk data to your db)